# Adding Ajax toolkit to web.config so it can be used throughout a project

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-config, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I would like to add the following to Web.config so the Ajax toolkit is available to my whole project because this is part of a tutorial I'm following from an ebook.

```
<pages theme="Blue">
  <controls>
⋮
    <add tagPrefix="atk" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
        assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

In our Web.config file there is no controls tag so I tried to add the controls tag and get an error telling me it is expecting child element controls. I'm assuming these child element controls are indicated by ⋮ in the ebook.

Can you tell me what child element controls need to be added so I can add the tagPrefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I changed this answer because your code looks just fine , assuming you have page and control in `<system.web>`  , also have you added AjaxControlToolkit in your bin folder?

```
<system.web>
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="Subtext.Web.Controls"
            namespace="Subtext.Web.Controls"
            tagPrefix="st" />
    <add src="~/Controls/SomeControl.ascx"
            tagName="SomeControl"
            tagPrefix="st" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for the help. Looking at your coding I see where I went wrong. The code in the post is from the ebook and my actual code had: <pages theme="Blue"/>. The "/" was messing me up. When I constructed the code like yours to have </pages> at the end, it worked. I originally added the toolkit dll file into the toolbox. Maybe that action also placed it in the bin folder. By the way, what is the path to that bin folder in case I need it?

Comment: You would have to make a bin folder, it sounds like yours is working fine without it though